# MVC 3 and LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to display the results of a sproc in my MVC 3 web app.
However, the sproc calls into 4 tables on one database and joins them with 5 views (single table views only, thank goodness) on another database.  Each (SQL Server) db is on a separate server but that shouldn't matter.

I've read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx 
and this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/linqToSql5.aspx
and still cannot determine whether I should use the dataContext classes or just embed the straight SQL.

Perhaps there is a better way to return my results than LINQ to SQL (15 columns, 3 different data types)?  I need to update the tables as well.  The user will have the ability to update each value if they choose.  Is this a task best suited for the entity framework classes?

I plan on using the repository pattern so I can change data access technology if I must but would rather make the correct decision the 1st go 'round.

I was hoping for a resource that was more up-to-date than say, NerdDinner and more robust than the movie apps for MVC3 that abound, particularly implementing the sproc results inside a view.  Any suggestions would surely be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you plan to "update" data then you are going to handle it all through stored procedures. Both Linq-to-sql or Entity framework will not help you with this because they are not able to persist changes to something created from arbitrary query. You should very carefully check if you are even able to track the data back to the correct record in the correct table. Generally result of a stored procedure is mostly for viewing the data but once you want to modify the data you must work with each table directly or again use some stored procedure which will do the task. Working with tables from multiple databases can be pretty complex in entity framework (EF doesn't support objects from multiple databases in one entity model).

Also what you mean by *15 columns, 3 different data types*? Stored procedures support in both Linq-to-sql and Entity framework will return enumeration of one flattened data type containing 15 properties.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick with LINQ to SQL which is where I feel most comfortable.  I had a feeling that neither technology would act on myreturned data object.  NOTE:  The 15/3 reference was specific to the "work with each table directly" part which I had already moved on to in my subconscious.  My apologies for mixing apples/oranges as you're point about the returned flat enumeration data type reveals.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything that linq-to-sql can do that Entity Framework can't really, so EF seems to be a better solution in this case. You can add a stored procedure to your Entity Framework model as well, so you can just have it call the procedure and deal with whatever comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Since the end goal will involve accessing the same Databases with either technology and they will be using sql to retrive the data either way its really a subjective anwser.

I would use whatever technology you are most comfortable and focus more on the implementation. Both data access platforms are based off of ado.net technologies and are for the most part equally powerful.

Regardless of the technology I would evaluate how the data is accessed and make implementation decisions based on that.